Calling Matlab function from command line in Python Problem
In my project I have a .m file whose name is SHROku.m with SHROku() function. When I call this function from Python like below command I successfully run the program.
subprocess.run(r"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\bin\matlab.exe  -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash  -r \"run('C:\Users\CY\Desktop\SHRoku(1, 3)');exit\" ")

However, if one of the parameters in the function is a string like filename, it gives an error like sending parameters "abc" to SHROku function.
subprocess.run(r"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\bin\matlab.exe  -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash  -r \"run('C:\Users\CY\Desktop\SHRoku(1, abc)');exit\" ")

Is there any solution for this problem?

Good morning. Please see how to ask and add a Minimal, reproducible example to your question

import subprocess

subprocess.run(r"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\bin\matlab.exe  -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash  -r \"run('C:\Users\cyapicioglu\Desktop\SHROku(1, \\\"asadada\\\")');exit\" ")

solve my issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
